# Remove space between nested braces

Tags: sed

How can I remove space between strings in between first occurrence of `(` and last occurrence of `)`.
Say if I have string like

```
(remove space ( fromthefile )between space).
```

I should get output as

```
(removespace(fromthefile)betweenspace).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in this way,

```
 $ echo "(remove space ( fromthefile )between space)." | sed ':l s/\(([^ )]*\)[ ]/\1/;tl'
  (removespace(fromthefile)betweenspace).
```

This will only remove whitespace between parentheses.

Another example,

```
 $ echo "foo bar(remove space ( fromthefile )between space)." | sed ':l s/\(([^ )]*\)[ ]/\1/;tl'
 foo bar(removespace(fromthefile)betweenspace).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.It worked for my requirement.It will be very helpful if you can explain how it is exactly happening.

Comment: Should this work with nested parentheses? It prints `(removespace(fromthefile)between space).` on `GNU sed 4.2.2`. I can't see how the match should work to find that space after the first `)`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how this could be done with just sed, since normal regexes [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302308/6372809) be [able to match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740/6372809) [nested parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/6372809). Luckily stuff like Perl supports not-so-regular expressions too, like this stolen from the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740/6372809):

```
echo "out side (in ( side ( ) ) remove ( spaces ) ) out ( in again )." |
 perl -lpe 's/\(([^()]|(?R))*\)/ local $_ = $&; s,\s+,,g; $_ /eg'
out side (in(side())remove(spaces)) out (inagain).
```

The (non-)regular expression works as follows:

```
\(([^()]+|(?R))*\)
^^|      |    ||^^  -- literal parenthesis, inside of which:
  ^      ^    ^|   --- group with choice:
   ^^^^^^ ^^^^ |  ---- anything except parenthesis, any number,
               |       OR this whole pattern again.
               ^ ----- any number of those two choices
```

The replacement part takes the matching string from `$&`, modifies it in a local variable, removing all whitespace characters, and returns the modified value. (`s///` doesn't work on `$&` or `$1` directly.)

Though it's easier if you know you only have one set of parenthesis on a single line, so can match from the first `(` to the last `)`.

```
echo "out (in ( side) here ) out again." | 
 perl -pe 's/\(.*\)/ $_ = $&; s,\s+,,g; $_ /e'
out (in(side)here) out again.
```

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't know if using `$_` inside the `s///e` can break, but it seems to work for me.</sub>